# Rails active records N+1 query problem when updating with relational data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I need to update multiple objects (`Assignments`) that belong to an other object (`Cursus`) with some of Cursus's data (`finished`).
I can do it easily but it queries each bar objects.

```rb
Assignment.includes(:cursus).each do |assignment|
  assignment.update(:finished => assignment.cursus.finished)
end
```

I tried to do something with `update_all` but couldn't do the joins properly.
( I know my issue comes from bad practices on the database schema design but I can't change it right now )

Comment: if all else fails, you can always fire off a raw sql snippet: `Foo.connection.execute("UPDATE foos SET .... FROM bars WHERE ...")` https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update-join/

Comment: Yea, but I'd rather stick to using the ORM.

Comment: I see why you'd want to do that. Well, good luck then.

Comment: Please use real world objects, `foo` `bar` & `baz` are meaningless, much easier to reason with objects you can identify with.

Comment: Sorry, my use case's object do not make a lot of sense on their own, I'll try to find something meaningfull

Comment: @Eyeslandic: but we don't care what they actually are. "They [metasyntactic variables] have been used to name entities such as variables, functions, and commands whose exact identity is unimportant and serve only to demonstrate a concept."

Comment: I don't mean what the op is actually using, I just mean objects like the ever-green books, chapters and authors or something else.... I just personally find it easier to wrap my head around objects I'm familiar with...

Comment: Agreed. I personally use books/chapters or order/line_items or something. But I found this particular case to be quite readable with foos and bars. I have this problem with reading generalized algorithms in books. "Ok, that's cool. Now can we get a step-by-step variant which uses books and chapters?" :)

Comment: Have you tried `eager_load` or `preload` instead of `includes`?

Comment: Speaking of includes vs joins, how about something like `Assignment.joins(:cursus).update_all("finished = cursus.finished")`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev this doesnt create the proper join an fails with `missing FROM-clause entry`
@Eyeslandic I've been trying to make it work with thoses too but it keeps querying each row.

Comment: "but it keeps querying each row" - querying/loading or updating? Or both? It _will_ update invididually, but should load all of them in one query.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev both, and I want neither

Comment: When/if you manage to make this work in ActiveRecord, please post a self-answer.